# CSS selector for a specific href attribute value

Tags: html, css

I am getting this code from the server-side. I don't have the server-side PHP code. Now I want to select all the PDF links using CSS selector. Is it possible? Looking forward to the answer. Thank you.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="file1.txt" target="_blank">Download Text File</a></li>
    <li><a href="file1.pdf" target="_blank">Download pdf File</a></li>
    <li><a href="file1.word" target="_blank">Download word File</a></li>
    <li><a href="file2.pdf" target="_blank">Download pdf File</a></li>
    <li><a href="file2.word" target="_blank">Download word File</a></li>
    <li><a href="file1.txt" target="_blank">Download Text File</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, You can do it using `a[href$=".pdf"]` for more details please read here.
https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

```css
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  background-color : red; 
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="file1.txt" target="_blank">Download Text File</a></li>
 <li><a href="file1.pdf" target="_blank">Download pdf File</a></li>
 <li><a href="file1.word" target="_blank">Download word File</a></li>
 <li><a href="file2.pdf" target="_blank">Download pdf File</a></li>
 <li><a href="file2.word" target="_blank">Download word File</a></li>
 <li><a href="file1.txt" target="_blank">Download Text File</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Use [an attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), specifically `$=` which matches suffixes:

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  /* … */
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 allows selecting with [attribute selector $=](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp):

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: So it would match `notapdf.pdf.txt`?

Comment: Fixed the answer.